# multiplying two lists of matrices in continuos form

Tags: r

I have two lists of matrices and I want to multiply the first element of the first list with the first element of the second list and so on, without writing every operatios due to may be a large number of elements on each list (both lists have the same length)

this is what I mean

```
'(colSums(R1*t(M1))),(colSums(R2*t(M2))),...(colSums(Rn*t(Mn)))'
```

Do I need to create an extra list?
Although first I must be able to transpose the matrices of one of the lists before multiplying them. The results will be used for easier operations.

I already tried to use indexes and loops and doesn't work,
first tried to transpose matrices in one list like this (M is one of the lists and the other is named R, M contains M1,M2,..Mn and the same for list R)

The complete operation looks like this:

```
'for (i in 1:length(M)){Mt<-list(t(M[[i]]))}'
```

and only applies it to the last element.

The full operation looks like this:

```
 '(cbind((colSums(R1*t(M1))),(colSums(R2*t(M2))),...(colSums(Rn*t(Mn))))'
```

any step of these will be useful

Answer (score 0):

you could use the rlist package.

The function

```
list.apply(.data, .fun, ...)
```

will apply a function to each list element.

You can find documentation at [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/rlist.pdf][1].

Comment: can you add an example?